# Is there a way to determine if code is being compiled via Xcode or via XCodeBuild?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I have a small piece of conditional code (used for testing purposes) that I'd like the behavior to change depending upon if the code is being built via Xcode to if its built via XCodeBuild (i.e. if the code is being built by a developer as opposed to being built by a build system).

Is there a way of determining this?

Comment: We use jenkins as our build system.  Each of our iOS builds has a pre-build shell script that edits a plist (defaults.plist in our case) using PlistBuddy to add a field that can then be checked for existence in the code.  That's the only way I could figure out how to do it, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks, that will do the job